# Can I compile visual studio solutions (.sln) without installing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Can I compile visual studio solutions (.sln) without installing visual studio. Can I install something like a VS SDK to do this?

The solution is a VC++ one.

Answer (score 12):

I think the SDK still comes with MSBuild and a barebones compiler. You might also want to look at "VS Express", depending on your reasons not to install Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't remember the details but there are command line utilities for this, I remember using them to automate the build for all the solutions from different developers.

Comment: Yes, MSBuild will do the trick (and will call VCBuild as needed for C++ projects in a solution).

Answer (score 10):

You can try call the MSBuild.exe which become wiht the .NET Framework 3.5 and probability with old versions too.
I actually use this for my NAnt builds.

use something like:

```
"dotnet.dir" /msbuild.exe ./solutionX.sln" /v:q /nologo /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use vcbuild.exe to do it. I believe it is included with the Windows SDK.

Certain C++ libraries such as MFC and ATL only ship as part of visual studio so you will need visual studio on the machine to build if you make use of any of these.

Answer (score 0):

Luís Custódio is right.
Visual Studio is launching msbuild under the hoods...

**Tip**
Change the setting for the verbosity of the build output to see some details in 
Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can separately install the MsBuild tools